# Find duration of a REST call in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I want to find out the time taken by a REST service to send back the promise object. If a REST service takes more than lets say *x* seconds, I need to show user a spinner and once the promise object is obtained the normal flow should proceed.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried so far. -1 until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recording the time of the request seems unnecessary.

Why not just always setup a timeout that will trigger the spinner after x seconds.
In the success callback of the promise you can just destroy the timeout object preventing it from triggering the spinner if it's before x seconds. Then remove the spinner if it exists.

```
var duration = 1000 * 1; //1 sec
var timeout = setTimeout(releaseTheSpinner, duration);
var releaseTheSpinner = function() {
  //Make spinner
}
Something.update(data).
success(function {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  //kill spinner
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `setTimeout` should suffice. For example:

```
$scope.useHttp = function() {
    $http.get('path/to/stuff')
        .success(function(data) {
            hideSpinner();
            //do stuff with data
        });
    setTimeout(showSpinner,1000); //will show the spinner after a second (1000 milliseconds).
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [ngProgress](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/#demo) directive or the [angular loading bar directive](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/), which place a progress at the top of the page.  This creates a general, uniform method of displaying progress.  Even if the service responds quickly (which is when you don't want to show a progress), the bar moves very quickly.  This isn't a direct answer to your question, but a suggested alternative to added complexity around timing and showing a spinner.